# undeleting with ntfsundelete

Tags: command-line, ntfs, data-recovery

trying to undelete some files using ntfsundelete:

```
sudo ntfsundelete /dev/sda1 -v -S 300m-20g -p 100 -o /mnt/bigboy/ntfsundelete/
```

but I am getting:

```
You must specify exactly one device.
```

as far as I can see, I am specifying the device I want to restore files from, and the location of the files.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this, [http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40953/14349](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40953/14349) I would have commented but I don't have the privilege level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the syntax needs to be `ntfsundelete [options] device`. So your example should look like this:

```
sudo ntfsundelete -v -S 300m-20g -p 100 -o /mnt/bigboy/ntfsundelete/ /dev/sda1
```

This worked for me, although I didn't specify the output `-o`. I just let it dump the data to the directory I was currently in.